# Flutter Carousel Slider Page value is only available after content dimensions are established error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, slider, carousel

When i set enlargecenterpage to true i get error "Page value is only available after content dimensions are established" when i set to false works fine also when i build in false and the set to true and reload app it also works fine but if i set it true at the start it gives that error

```
Column(                            
children: [
                              CarouselSlider.builder(
                                options: CarouselOptions(
                                  autoPlay: true,
                                  pageSnapping: true,
                                  autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                                  enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                                  pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                                ),
                                itemCount: 10,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index,
                                        int page) =>
                                    ClipRRect(
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .height /
                                              3,
                                          width:
                                              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
```

Answer (score 0):

switching to flutter stable fixed the issue